# Decomposing a Klein bottle into a single Möbius strip.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Lambda$ be a simple closed curve on the Klein bottle $K$. How do we position $\Lambda$ so that cutting along it produces a single Möbius strip? I can see how to decompose $K$ into two Möbius strips, but not one.

How do we prove that this is possible?

Comment: It's explained [here](http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/us27i_klpr.htm) in the text next to figure 4.